# retaining the state of webview across activities - android

Tags: android, webview

I have two activities activity A and activity B, in activity B i am using webview to load the url, it goes well upto here, but when i switch back from Activity B to A and back to B webview doesn't show me the previous state of the page, it againg reloads the url, i have tried to restore the webview using onSaveInstanceState but in onCreate the savedInstanceState always returns null

Can someone please post some pseudo/sample code? or atleast give me tips to overcome this probloem.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I would say easiest way I can think of doing this is:

1. Make your webview somehow static, either by holding its instance in a separate class and having a method which returns the same instance.
2. You can use a Fragment also, make its instance static. But while doing this make sure to override onResume() and other callbacks efficiently.

By just passing in bundle you can not save the state of what has already been loaded into the webview.